# Preg_Split delim number and string

Tags: php, regex, preg-split

I have a problem with `preg_split`. I need a regex to split my string into number and character. An example of my string is:

```
1_AB_CD_2_ABC_3_ABD
```

and I want a result splitted:

```
1
AB_CD
2
ABC
3
ABD
```

I've tried with this regex expression but this one not work:

```
 preg_split("/(^\d)(?=_)|(?<=_)(\d)(?=_)/",$sequence,PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE).
```

Comment: Did you try like this: https://ideone.com/ifHMJ0 ?

Comment: what would be the result for `2_AB_3 _AB_CD_ER_1` ?

Comment: Hi @stribizhev i've tried your code with a real example but this is the result: https://ideone.com/WL2Vxs. Thanks anyway...

Comment: @TusharGupta the result for your string: 2 AB 3 AB_CD_ER 1

Comment: @VincenzoDiRoberto: what about https://ideone.com/MLA5gk? Here is a regex101 demo: https://regex101.com/r/hL6tS5/1

Answer (score 1):

```
(?<=\d)_(?=[A-Z0-9]{2})|(?<=[A-Z0-9]{2})_(?=\d)
```

Try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/uE3cC4/26

```
$returnValue = preg_split('/(?<=\\d)_(?=[A-Z0-9]{2})|(?<=[A-Z0-9]{2})_(?=\\d)/', '1_AB_CD_2_ABC_3_ABD', -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

Comment: I've tried your solution but not work. :(  Splitted string are incorrect

Comment: I've tried your solution:                                                 ($result=preg_split("/(?<=\d)_(?=[A-Z])|(?<=[A-Z])_(?=\d)/",$sequence))                                                                 but not work. :(  Splitted string are incorrect : 1_ITBI1303000100_2_ITTO10051004_3_ITTO10060018_4_ITBI1303000100 return with this expression "1 ITBI1303000100_2 ITTO10051004_3 ITTO10060018_4 ITBI1303000100 "....

Comment: Sorry but with preg_split still doesn't work. I've tried with or without PREG_DELIM_CAPTURE                                                      $result=preg_split("/(?<=\\d)_(?=[A-Z])|(?<=[A-Z])_(?=\\d)/",$sequence,PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE)                                                   $result=preg_split("/(?<=\\d)_(?=[A-Z])|(?<=[A-Z])_(?=\\d)/",$sequence)

Comment: @VincenzoDiRoberto it is working for me.I have included the working code as well in the naswer.dont know what's d issue at ur end :(

Comment: i have already tried your demo with real string and your demo doesn't work :( You can test it with this string:1_ITBI1303000100_2_ITTO10051004_3_ITTO10060018_4_ITBI1303000100

Comment: it works well in every case but not in this one: "1_HUB _SIT_RIVALTA_2_HUB_3SAAA_3_IT8739292" because there is a possibility that a segment has number and string and can start with number.... i know it is very difficult :(